# Excel Countifs variable does not read

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When I do this with a Sumifs formula it works. But when I try with countifs connecting to a list of names I have and want it to read it does not work. What am I missing from the formula?  The Sheet1!$E$6:$E$15 is where the list of names are located I want to look and count for specifically.

{=COUNTIFS(ROOM,'Attendance Output'!B10,SERIES,Sheet1!$E$6:$E$15)}

Comment: You're mixing the types I believe. `=COUNTIFS([criteria 1 range],[criteria1],[criteria 2 range ],[criteria 2], etc)`...Your formula, I think, is using `=COUNTIFS(range, criteria, criteria, range)`?  If `SERIES` is a named range to a single cell, try switching `SERIES` and `Sheet1!E6:E15`.

Comment: try `=SUM(COUNTIFS(ROOM,'Attendance Output'!B10,SERIES,Sheet1!$E$6:$E$15))` as a standard (non-array) formula.

Comment: It has to be an array formula; not a standard formula as previously stated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a count for when the named range ROOM is equal to 'Attendance Output'!B10 and the named range SERIES is any of the values in Sheet1!$E$6:$E$15.

As an array/CSE formula,

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(ROOM, 'Attendance Output'!B10, SERIES, Sheet1!$E$6:$E$15))
```

Comment: Or you can use SUMPRODUCT instead of SUM, It does not require CSE.

Comment: Ah yes! That's what I was thinking about! Thanks for catching that.

Comment: When I used the SUM it worked. That was what I was missing. But I had to use Ctrl + Shift + Enter to make it work.